# What method ga4 use for streaming data to bigquery? In SQL terms, is it just insert or update too?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

Sorry, I'm new to this. I read a few sources including some google documentation guides but still don't quiet understand:

Every time GA4 streams data into bigquery, bigquery table get a new row, or it can update existing?
For example, if I want data from a particular client_id should I expect only 1 row, or I get a bunch with different data to research?

Comment: I didn't have much knowledge on GA4 but I don't think BigQuery streaming updates the existing row based on `client_id`. Basically BigQuery  doesn't have PK concept.  If a user make a bunch of activities in your website, you will get a bunch of data when you query a user from BigQuery with `client_Id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every record should be insert entry as if you see table column , each streamed record loaded with epoch timestamp as event_timestamp.

[image]